# Could not use realtime-android library

Tags: android, import, android-library

I want to use this [realtime-android](https://github.com/goodow/realtime-android) project  as a library in my Android project, but when I try to import this project it gives me this "No projects are found to import".

So what to do to use it as a library? 
Thank you for your help.
this the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
    compile project(':gridlayout_v7')
    compile 'com.goodow.realtime:realtime-android:0.5.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Gradle, or did you download it as a JAR?

Comment: I've download this project from the github but I couldn't import it into my workspace  to add it as a library to my current project.

Comment: Why do you need to download the project from Github?

Comment: Also, you would need to import it as a Maven project, not a Java project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Maven Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.goodow.realtime/realtime-android/0.5.0), you can just include it in your `build.gradle` dependency section.

I notice that you are missing the `repositories` section, so you may want to add that. Here is my build.gradle, for example.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    // ... other stuff

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.2.1"

    // this line
    compile 'com.goodow.realtime:realtime-android:0.5.0'

}
```

Or you could use the Download JAR button and drop it into the `libs/` folder of your project.

Comment: I included this line in build.gradle, and then what I should do to make it work?  I've already drop the project into the libs/ but the import still cannot be resolved.

Comment: You only need to use gradle **or** download the JAR, not both. I would recommend gradle. Also, what are you trying to import? I can do `import com.goodow.realtime.android.AndroidPlatform;` just fine with no errors.

Comment: I added that line and then clean the project but the import still cannot be resolved. I'm trying to import com.goodow.realtime.android.AndroidPlatform too.

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36020853/edit) your question to include the full build.gradle file?

Comment: @SDH So it works? I think if you rebuild the project after a clean, it should download that library and allow you to import.

Comment: It dosen't work :(, but I did all what I should do, I'm giving up.

Comment: I'm using the latest Android Studio and a relatively new project and I can import fine, so I don't know what to tell you :(

Comment: I think you are missing a `repository` section, actually to tell Gradle where to download stuff from.

Comment: it should be, I think I should switch to maven project

Comment: Gradle works the same as Maven for dependency management. I've edited my answer to include my Gradle file

Comment: I assume you used Eclipse before?